# Responsive images in an email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've been reading about [srcset](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/), seems like a good way to handle responsive images.

I was just wondering, would this work for images in emails? Or is there a better way to have responsive imagery in emails?

Comment: A bit of googling suggests support for srcset in email clients is limited; [this blog posts reports that iPhone 6 supports it, but Mac's Mail.app does not](http://mikevoermans.com/development/email-srcset-testing) (that post is from Oct 2014 though, so maybe it's outdated). There aren't really any better options for responsive images though, so you'll probably still want to use srcset. Just be sure to test in every mail client you can get your hands on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support is going to be spotty. According to [this article](http://mikevoermans.com/development/email-srcset-testing), it is only supported in iOS 6.

You can resize images with media queries in your `<style>` section. But as far as sourcing different sizes with `srcset`, your going to have to do some testing with a service like Litmus to get an idea of current support.

It's too bad there isn't a resource like CanIUse for html email...

Comment: Tempting to buy "caniuseinemails.com" as a one-pager that just says "No, you probably can't"...

Comment: a decent resource on acceptable CSS is https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/. It is not quite as comprehensive as CanIUse, but is a great reference.

Comment: There's also this website now: https://www.caniemail.com

You can see `srcset` support over here: https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-srcset/